# Kentico 9 REST service 403 error

Tags: kentico

I have a custom page type (kff.SeasonCTA), that I'm trying to access. The goal is the present the data from the custom pages on a static HTML page using jQuery. I've confirmed the REST service is working as i can get the county json object as per the documentation.

I've set authentication to Basic, and the service enabled as Both. I generated a hash with this URL: http://dev.knowledgefirstfinancial.ca/rest/kff.SeasonalCTA?format=json

I get a 403. I read more, and i think it's because i'm doing an ALL. So how can i specify only published pages.

Or is it possible to get all the child data from a cms.folder if i specify the folder by it's GUID?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using basic authentication: create user account and make sure it has all necessary permissions (use impersonation to verify access) and pass that user in authorization header.

It is possible to request all the child by node alias path:

```
/content/currentsite/<culture>/childrenof/<alias path> 
/content/currentsite/en-us/childrenof/news
```

Comment: Do you need /rest/ before those paths?

Comment: Thought so. I'm just seeing waht the xml is returned in the browser, then I'll start with my JS. This is public info on the site, so I think Basic with a hash should be ok.

Comment: I'm getting an empty xml node: <csm_documents/> returned.

Comment: have you verified if user, you're making request with, has needed access?

Comment: try forms authentication, so it will process request for your account (I assume global admin) and you'll see if this is permissions issue or not

Comment: When i plug this into my js code, i'm getting Auth errors. At least i know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142194/discussion-between-roman-hutnyk-and-mark-handy).